# Is async_receive_from always receive full message in handler?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

In all samples I've found, I could not see any buffering. Does it mean that in handler I'm receiving always full message? Not chunked.
I can not find any answer on that in documentation.

> Is `boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::async_receive_from` always receive
>   full message in handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDP can be fragmented on low OSI level, but in higher level it is not possible.

You dont need to worry about this, you always receive full datagram (or do not receive it at all).